# Can we call an entire python script in Julia instead of just individual functions?

Tags: python, julia

I am new to both Julia and Python, and am on OS X. I am aware of the PyCall package that allows you to call individual Python functions and import Python modules. However, is there a way to call an entire .py python script in Julia? I have a Julia script as sort of a wrapper script and would prefer to just call the .py script instead of rewriting the entire .py script in Julia using the PyCall module and different syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `run`? It doesn't depend on PyCall.jl and looks much simpler to me:

```
shell> cat hello.py
print("hello, world")

julia> run(`python hello.py`)
hello, world
```

Answer (score 5):

`execfile` is available, just as in Python itself.

```
shell> cat test.py
from __future__ import print_function
print("hello, world")

julia> pyeval("execfile(x)", x="test.py")
hello, world
```